# Do I need to update an SSL's contact info in some way?

Tags: security-certificate

As far as I know, SSL certificates do not contain contact information such as phone number. However, contact information is probably stored somewhere in order to contact me concerning the SSL cert if the need arises. Or am I wrong about this?

I bought an SSL certificate (from a reseller, if this matters), and have since acquired a new phone number. I have updated that new number at the reseller's website, so that's taken care of. The question is - is there need to update my contact info anywhere else?

Comment: As long as your reseller can contact you to invoice you you should be right.  But this leads to the question of why you are paying for a certificate with the existence of LetsEncrypt free SSL certs.  Unless of course you need an EV cert.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already updated your new contact information with the reseller, then there's no need to update your contact information anywhere else.